# Checkmark next to website title in browser tab?

Tags: browser, mamp

I'm developing a site on my local machine, and on every browser after the document is ready a checkmark is prepended to the corresponding tab.

[image: Browser tab with checkmark]

There is a noticeable small delay before this checkmark appears on page refresh, and it has nothing to do with JavaScript (tried disabling).  At one time, IE running on Parallels prepended an "X" to my document title.  Lately it has been just showing the checkmark.

Anyone have any idea what this is?  I'm using `MAMP` with Apache listening on port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is being done by [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/).  I'm not sure why or how the checkmark showed up even with JS disabled; it might have been a fluke.  But for the curious, it turns out QUnit alters the document title.